# determining if an integer exists in a set in O(1) expected time and O(logn) worst case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

i need describe a data structure that is able to determine where or not a particular integer exists in a set in O(1) expected time and O(logn) worst case also consuming O(n) space. ive had a look at a table containing common data structures and there big-O time/space complexities but i cant seem to find any that fit these requirements? is there a way to modify a BST to fit these requirements?

Comment: This describes a hashmap/set.

Comment: worst case is O(n) for hashmap/set not O(logn) @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Carcigenicate commented, a hashmap exhibits the behavior you want.  It has constant `O(1)` expected lookup time, except in the case of collisions.  In the case of collisions, hashmaps typically create a list of items for a given bucket.  In the worst case scenario, a hashmap would behave like a list.  But this would imply a worst case search time of `O(n)`, which does not fit your requirement.

Java, in its latest 8 version, exposed a `HashMap` class which uses balanced trees instead of lists to store items which collide with the same bucket.  This guarantees a worst case search time of `O(logn)`.

So, to solve your problem, you would need to modify the implementation of a hashmap to use trees for collisions.  If you are using Java 8, then life is already good and you can just run with `HashMap`.

Comment: ahh i see so instead of having a linked list, they simply just switch it for a tree?

Comment: @101ldaniels Yes, do this and then resulting hashmap should behave in line with what you need.

Comment: I think the `O(log n)` only applies if your keys implement 'Comparable', otherwise it may still degenerate to `O(n)`.